# Change color of parents when child link is active

Tags: html, css

I want to do something like this. I have a link inside a parent and I want to change the background of the parent and the link both whenever I click on the link. Is it possible?

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x5m5m035/

```
a:active {
   background-color: yellow;
}
div{
   background-color: red; 
}
```

So when I click on the link, parent's background color should also be yellow.

I am sorry if it is too silly to ask.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Not without JS. I presume there's some reason why you don't just style the link to be like a `div`? (eg: http://jsfiddle.net/x5m5m035/2/)

Comment: I cannot change html. That is the reason

Comment: If you make the `<a>` block-level you it would fill the `<div>` and you wouldn't have the issue (http://jsfiddle.net/x5m5m035/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible using pure CSS because CSS hasn't parent selector, but you can do that using javascript or JQuery.

Try this JQuery code for instance:

```
$('a').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).parent("div").css("background-color","yellow");
}).mouseup(function() {
    $(this).parent("div").css("background-color","red");
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x5m5m035/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to implement if without scripts.